# Do I need to keep the Certificate Signing Request(CSR) file?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Is the Certificate Signing Request(CSR) file something I should backup and keep? Or is it something thats really one time use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one-time use file. You can delete it.

See [this page on the Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/32857).